# Openvpn multiple clients same machine

Tags: ubuntu, networking, openvpn, ubuntu-16.04

I would like to achieve the following:

Each user in my system (ubuntu 16.04) needs to be able to connect to different vpn servers and all the processes from this user route all the traffic from the corresponding vpn.

Example:
Let's say we have 2 system users and each one of them has "bought" one vpn service from ipvanish.
He should be able when he login's to his shell to :

```
openvpn --config ipvanish-AT-Vienna-vie-c04.ovpn --auth-user-pass userpass --ca ca.ipvanish.com.crt
```

and all his traffic (from the processes he started) should go through this vpn.

Similarly another system user should be able to do the same

```
openvpn --config  ipvanish-AE-Dubai-dxb-c01.ovpn     --auth-user-pass userpass --ca ca.ipvanish.com.crt
```

and start a new vpn connection.

vpn config files are here: https://www.ipvanish.com/software/configs/

Do you know how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

By design the network layer is shared for all users logged on the server .

you need to create a virtual machine by user , or a light container lxc .

Comment: I figured out that it can be done using Network Namespaces (netns), so a vm is not needed.

Comment: Some people do it . => http://www.naju.se/articles/openvpn-netns.html